# who are all you zombies? a (mangled) quote from a 1980s(?) science fiction story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, timeline

I'm looking for a short story where a guy goes back in time (I think repeatedly in some form) and the story ends with the guy either wondering or getting confused (or maybe just making a statement about) his identity. Something like "I know who I am but who are all you zombies?!"   What story is this?

The story might be from the 1980s. Or it might predate that by one or more decades.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying a short story about time travel and paradoxes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/identifying-a-short-story-about-time-travel-and-paradoxes)

Comment: I'm really surprised that Googling the quote you knew didn't turn up any results for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying a short story about time travel and paradoxes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42822/identifying-a-short-story-about-time-travel-and-paradoxes)

Comment: Not a dup. OP has not accepted the answer.

Answer (score 40):

That's " '—**[All You Zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies)**—' " by Robert A. Heinlein. 1960, available to read [here](https://www.parallelreality-bg.com/images/stories/Ezoterika1/predestination/all%20you%20zombies.pdf)

The main character (a time traveler) winds up being his own father and mother, and says, just before the story ends, "I know where I came from -- but where did all you zombies come from?" (He is born and raised female, is seduced, has a baby, discovers that he also has male organs and that her female organs are wrecked, becomes a man, gets recruited into the Time Patrol (by himself), seduces his earlier female self, and takes the resulting baby girl back in time to be raised as him/herself.)

Heinlein really did like solipsism...

Comment: Was this an inspiration for the movie Predestination? Sounds very similar

Comment: It was, yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)

Comment: Technically the em dash (or possibly two, one at each end) is part of the title. Heinlein titled several stories that way. I *think* it indicates that the title is an incomplete, truncated thought, the way others would use an ellipsis. "—All You Zombies—" would be from the quote in question, "—And He Built a Crooked House—" from the traditional poem, "—We Also Walk Dogs" from the advertisement in the story which ends on those words, etc.